# Is there a more effective way to give random values to Button elements in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, random

I have 4 Button elements in a row in my Activity. I have four statis value and I want to assign these values to buttons randomly, after each button push.

At the moment I wrote a generator method which generates 4 different values and set the button values to them. I'm wondering, maybe there's a more effective tool to do this task in Android?

The generator:

```
public void generator(View view) {
        int one = new Random().nextInt(4);
        int two;
        do {
            two = new Random().nextInt(4);
        } while (two == one);
        int three;
        do {
            three = new Random().nextInt(4);
        } while (three == one || three == two);
        int four;
        do {
            four = new Random().nextInt(4);
        } while (four == one || four == two || four == three);
        buttonOnebutton.setText(String.valueOf(one));
        buttonTwobutton.setText(String.valueOf(two));
        buttonThreebutton.setText(String.valueOf(three));
        buttonFourbutton.setText(String.valueOf(four));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in another way. Create a collection of integers (List or array) and shuffle it. In the end you'll get collection of unique integers in the random order.

---

Create a collection at some point of time, it would be better to do it once, on the initialisation of the class.

```
int size = 4;
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(size);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    numbers.add(i);
}
```

Shuffle it and assign text to buttons

```
public void generator(View view) {
    Collections.shuffle(numbers); // java.util.Collections
    buttonOnebutton.setText(String.valueOf(numbers.get(0));
    buttonTwobutton.setText(String.valueOf(numbers.get(1)));
    ...
}
```

Collection can contain anything you need, e.g. strings

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("first", "second", "third", "fourth");
// list = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"]
Collections.shuffle(list);
// at this point list will be in random order, 
// e.g. list = ["third", "fourth", "second", "first"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I will use the shuffle method from now, it looks good for my current task as well.